# Crystal Report : Print multiple Bills on same page

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to save customer's page (space) and I'm sure each bill will not have more than 4-5 records in detail section. I'm having exactly same issue posted on below URL, can anybody help me on this?

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=14981

Note: I'm using crystal report for visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will not solve easily since you will have the problem to enforce a fix height of this sections but having dynamic number of records. I guess you will need to work with fix-height detail bands in sub reports and you will need to ensure that all customers will have the same count of detail records. There fore, you may need to make a temporary print table that you use to insert empty-records.

You need to work with a sub report and you need to work with a multi-column layout (with two columns) in the main report. 
The main report will only select the main record, not the detail records.

In the sub-report, you need to select the temporary detail table which ensures that all customers have the same detail record count and that the sub report will have the A6 height with that fix record count.

No good solution, but I guess any solution will require some temporary prepared data...